# How can I fix this IndexError?

Tags: python

I am working on a Python project that turns your speech into words then puts it into a Google Sheet. This is some of the logic and it is not quite working...

```
text = "First and 10 gain of 10 yards"
words = text.lower().split()
length = len(words)

print(words)

i = 0

for i in range(length):
    print(i)

    if words[i] == 'and':
        words[i] = '-'

    if words[i] == 'first':
        words[i] = '1'

for i in range(length):
    if words[i] == '-':
        words[i - 1 : i + 1] = [''.join(words[i - 1 : i + 1])]
        i = i + 1
        length = length - 1

print(words)
```

Here's the output:

```
['first', 'and', '10', 'gain', 'of', '10', 'yards']
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testing.py", line 48, in <module>
    if words[i] == '-':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Which line is line 48? I'll bet it's in the second for loop, not the first one. And that would mean your print statement isn't telling you where the error is happening.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, the traceback indicates the line: `if words[i] == '-':`, which is in the second loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: So why did you print the iteration index in the first loop and not the second?

Comment: @ThePhoton Are you replying to me? I'm not OP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including expected output. Also note that both `i =` statements do nothing. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask]. I also agree with Tomerikoo: you'd benefit from learning how to do your own debugging.

Comment: this is because `words[i - 1 : i + 1]` ... there is no `i+1` when `i == length`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that in your code:

```
for i in range(length):
    if words[i] == '-':
        words[i - 1 : i + 1] = [''.join(words[i - 1 : i + 1])]
        i = i + 1
        length = length - 1
```

you are modifying the list of words which results in the loop running beyond the length of the list.

You can address this problem as follows:

```
ptr = 0
while ptr < len(words):
    if words[ptr] == '-':
        words[ptr-1:ptr+1] = [''.join(words[ptr -1: ptr+1])]
    ptr += 1
```

Output:

```
['1-', '10', 'gain', 'of', '10', 'yards']
```

Comment: @GrahamFreeman Just a small advice: the fact that it worked doesn't mean it should be used (no offence to the answerer). Your question is really not clear and you didn't even explain what it is you are actually trying to do. If you would do so, we might suggest a much simpler way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the value of `length` assuming this will affect `range(length)` so the loop will run up to the new value of `length` - 1. But the problem is `range(length)` returns an inmutable sequence, so the loop will always run up to the value of `length` given at the start of the loop - 1. In other words, if the list is 7 elements in length, the loop will iterate 7 times regardless of your changes to the `length` variable.

Follow @itprorh66's suggestion.

Comment: Mutability has nothing to do with it. The problem is that the `expression_list` part of a [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) is evaluated once. I think that's what you meant, but you just have the mechanics a little confused :)

Comment: @wjandrea, ranges do not provide all the values at once, but calculate "individual items and subranges as needed." https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

Comment: @cesarv I'm aware of that. What I'm saying is, the cause of the problem is in the syntax, not the data.

Comment: @wjandrea, not really. Run this: `L = [1, 2, 3] (newline) for e in L: (newline) print(e) (newline) if e == 2: L.remove(3)`. It won't fail even though the `expression_list` part of the for statement is evaluated once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241106/discussion-between-cesarv-and-wjandrea).

Answer (score -1):

The second time you use `for i in range(length)`, you are setting `i` to be in the range from 0 to the `length`, however, this range is only calculated once and becomes an immutable sequence.

Then you modify the list with this line:

`words[i - 1 : i + 1] = [''.join(words[i - 1 : i + 1])]`

this is shortening the list and `i` ends up bigger than the index.

If you change the logic around the second for loop to:

```
i = 0
while i < length:
    if words[i] == '-':
        words[i - 1 : i + 1] = [''.join(words[i - 1 : i + 1])]
        length = length - 1
    i = i + 1
```

It will work.

Comment: That is simply not true. The line `i = i + 1` has no effect whatsoever... (same for the line `length = length - 1` for that matter)